# For what do I use the appProperty property?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I recently stumpled over the `appProperty` within the the `Ext.app.Application` class and wondered why would I use it. I would require access to App instance anyway to then access a variable that again contains the instance? Maybe I am stupied but for what is this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a misunderstanding here; The `name` property just defines a namespace of the Application along with a getter Method for it (`getApplication()`) but it will not provide you with the current instance of that application unless you call the getter or use the new `appProperty`.

Lets say you have the following application

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'App',
    appProperty: 'instance',
    launch: function() {
        // some more code
    }
});
```

the you can access this application from any Component by calling either

```
App.getApplicatio();
```

or

```
App.instance
```

Where the second will be bit faster cause it is no method call and for sure you can define the name of this property. So I guess you see this property is quite useful!

> *Note that a namespace is always a object in javascript. That is the
>   reason why you are able to place properties into it.*

Comment: I see. Ok, the question was a bit stupied. Thanks for elaborating.